# Mongodb when use db vs collections

Tags: mongodb

I would like to know what is the goal of creating separate db in mongodb

Basically for my project I have almost 10 collections.

- 1 for users
- 1 for users activities
- 1 for relations between users
- Some for user dedicated features
- Some for all configuration purpose

Is there an interest to split my collections in different dbs ?

I know that mongo is used to scale vertically and not horizontally so I am wondering about the goal of creating several database (except to sort my collections in category)

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDb Database vs Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937806/mongodb-database-vs-collection)

Comment: I already read this however tge approach of this guy is different. He wanted to know how to spreas users accros collections, inside a collection or accross dbs. On my side all my users are in same collection. However I have several collections with different goals. My interest is between collection and db